# select from table as another table with additional characters

Tags: php, sql, concatenation

i have a table with many integers, it's index
eg `235,567,2,43,45,66,7`

I want each record to have the coma character at the beggining and the end of the string
eg. `,235,567,2,43,45,66,7,`

Is it possible to make a query like this?

```
select ','.data.',' from mytable as testtable
```

I know this can't work but any suggestions?

Comment: Look into `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: solved it by SELECT CONCAT(',', `myfield`, ',') from mytable;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(  ",", data,  "," ) 
FROM mytable
```

Is that what you're looking for? Just commas at the beginning and end of your returned result?

Answer (score 2):

yes, use `CONCAT()`

```
select CONCAT(',', data, ',') from mytable as testtable
```

or `CONCAT_WS()`

```
select CONCAT_WS(',', data) from mytable as testtable
```

---

if you have rows like these:

```
data
1
2
3
4
```

and your desired output is `,1,2,3,4,`, then use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
select CONCAT_WS(',', GROUP_CONCAT(data)) from mytable as testtable
```

Comment: is there anything you would like to know more?